# MYSQL Where DAY-1

Tags: mysql, events

After searching a lot I post here because I can't find an answer.

I'm trying to make a mysql event that update my table every midnight and change a field if the day equal the yesterday day number.

Example:

```
------------------------------                          ------------------------------
| id | day | month | expired |   If today is the 13     | id | day | month | expired |
------------------------------   and now are the        ------------------------------
|  1 |  12 |     1 |       0 |   00:01 it would have    |  1 |  12 |     1 |       1 |
------------------------------   to become like this    ------------------------------
|  2 |  13 |     1 |       0 |                  --->    |  2 |  13 |     1 |       0 |
------------------------------                          ------------------------------
```

This is the query I will use to trigger the event, however I don't know how to update only the row with `day = current_day_number - 1 and month = current_month_number`.

```
CREATE EVENT cl_reservations
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY  
STARTS '2014-1-18 00:00:01'   
DO UPDATE `jc_classes`.`cl_reservations` SET `expired` =  '0' WHERE ???
```

Thanks a lot for any help =D

Comment: It is bad idea o keep date parts separately. Put them together and use WHERE `date` = DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 1 DAY

Comment: i have to keep them separately because of the use i do with them in php.. is there a way to make your query work for day and month separately?